# UnsatisfiableError - Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create my own anaconda package and after many attempts I've finally managed to create a conda usable [package](https://anaconda.org/monomonedula/sten) out of my [code](https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding/tree/refactor%26cleanup). (It depends on a package from haasad channel, so it should be installed like this:
`conda install -c monomonedula sten -c haasad`).

The problem appear when I'm trying to install a package called [stellargraph](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph) in the same environment:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                       

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

The most frustrating part here is missing output for what packages are actually conflicting. Why is it empty & how do I fix it?

UPD.
On another machine it suddenly showed which dependencies are actually conflicting, but it still hard to make sense of it. So once again, how do I fix this?

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package numpy conflicts for:
stellargraph -> gensim[version='>=3.4.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.12.1,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0']
stellargraph -> numpy[version='>=1.14']

Package scipy conflicts for:
stellargraph -> scipy[version='>=1.1.0']
stellargraph -> gensim[version='>=3.4.0'] -> scipy[version='>=0.18.1']

Package numpy-base conflicts for:
sten -> numpy -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0',build='py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36hdbf6ddf_6|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py27h2b20989_7|py37h2b20989_7|py27h2b20989_7|py37hdbf6ddf_7|py37hdbf6ddf_8|py27hdbf6ddf_8|py35hdbf6ddf_8|py37h7cdd4dd_9|py37h3dfced4_9|py36h3dfced4_9|py35h3dfced4_9|py37h81de0dd_9|py27h74e8950_9|py35h74e8950_9|py37h74e8950_9|py27h81de0dd_9|py27h74e8950_10|py36h74e8950_10|py35h81de0dd_10|py37h2f8d375_10|py27h2f8d375_11|py36hde5b4d6_11|py37hde5b4d6_11|py37h2f8d375_12|py27h2f8d375_12|py37hde5b4d6_12|py36hde5b4d6_12|py38hde5b4d6_12|py38h2f8d375_12|py36h9be14a7_1|py27h2b20989_0|py36h2b20989_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_0|py27h2b20989_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_1|py37hdbf6ddf_1|py36h2b20989_2|py36hdbf6ddf_2|py27h2b20989_3|py27h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_4|py36h2b20989_4|py36hdbf6ddf_4|py35h2b20989_4|py36h2f8d375_4|py27h2f8d375_4|py37h81de0dd_4|py36h81de0dd_4|py37h2f8d375_5|py37hde5b4d6_5|py37h7cdd4dd_0|py35h7cdd4dd_0|py27h3dfced4_0|py37h3dfced4_0|py36h74e8950_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py37h81de0dd_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py37hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py37hde5b4d6_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py38h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py38hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_1|py27h81de0dd_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py37h74e8950_0|py27h74e8950_0|py35h74e8950_0|py35h3dfced4_0|py36h3dfced4_0|py36h7cdd4dd_0|py27h7cdd4dd_0|py36hde5b4d6_5|py27hde5b4d6_5|py27h2f8d375_5|py36h2f8d375_5|py38hde5b4d6_4|py38h2f8d375_4|py35h81de0dd_4|py27h81de0dd_4|py35h2f8d375_4|py37h2f8d375_4|py35hdbf6ddf_4|py37hdbf6ddf_4|py37h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_3|py36hdbf6ddf_3|py37hdbf6ddf_3|py37h2b20989_3|py36h2b20989_3|py37hdbf6ddf_2|py27hdbf6ddf_2|py37h2b20989_2|py27h2b20989_2|py27h2b20989_1|py36hdbf6ddf_1|py27hdbf6ddf_1|py37h2b20989_1|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py35h2b20989_0|py35h9be14a7_1|py27h9be14a7_1|py35h0ea5e3f_1|py27h0ea5e3f_1|py36h0ea5e3f_1|py27hde5b4d6_12|py36h2f8d375_12|py27hde5b4d6_11|py36h2f8d375_11|py37h2f8d375_11|py35h2f8d375_10|py27h2f8d375_10|py36h2f8d375_10|py36h81de0dd_10|py37h81de0dd_10|py27h81de0dd_10|py35h74e8950_10|py37h74e8950_10|py35h81de0dd_9|py36h74e8950_9|py36h81de0dd_9|py27h3dfced4_9|py27h7cdd4dd_9|py35h7cdd4dd_9|py36h7cdd4dd_9|py35h2b20989_8|py27h2b20989_8|py37h2b20989_8|py36h2b20989_8|py36hdbf6ddf_8|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py27hdbf6ddf_7|py36h2b20989_7|py37h2b20989_7|py37hdbf6ddf_7|py35h2b20989_7|py35hdbf6ddf_7|py36h2b20989_7|py36hdbf6ddf_7|py27hdbf6ddf_6|py37hdbf6ddf_6|py37h2b20989_6|py36h2b20989_6|py27h2b20989_6|py36hde5b4d6_0']
stellargraph -> numpy[version='>=1.14'] -> numpy-base[version='1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.17.0',build='py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h9be14a7_1|py27h2b20989_0|py36h2b20989_0|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_0|py27h2b20989_0|py36hdbf6ddf_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py36h2b20989_1|py37hdbf6ddf_1|py36h2b20989_2|py36hdbf6ddf_2|py27h2b20989_3|py27h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_4|py36h2b20989_4|py36hdbf6ddf_4|py35h2b20989_4|py36h2f8d375_4|py27h2f8d375_4|py37h81de0dd_4|py36h81de0dd_4|py37h2f8d375_5|py37hde5b4d6_5|py37h7cdd4dd_0|py35h7cdd4dd_0|py27h3dfced4_0|py37h3dfced4_0|py36h74e8950_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py37h81de0dd_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_1|py27h2f8d375_1|py37hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_1|py37h2f8d375_1|py37hde5b4d6_1|py36hde5b4d6_1|py27hde5b4d6_1|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_0|py37hde5b4d6_0|py38h2f8d375_0|py27hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py38hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py36h2f8d375_1|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36hde5b4d6_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py36h81de0dd_1|py27h81de0dd_1|py36h2f8d375_1|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py27h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py27h2f8d375_0|py35h2f8d375_0|py35h81de0dd_0|py37h81de0dd_0|py37h74e8950_0|py27h74e8950_0|py35h74e8950_0|py35h3dfced4_0|py36h3dfced4_0|py36h7cdd4dd_0|py27h7cdd4dd_0|py36hde5b4d6_5|py27hde5b4d6_5|py27h2f8d375_5|py36h2f8d375_5|py38hde5b4d6_4|py38h2f8d375_4|py35h81de0dd_4|py27h81de0dd_4|py35h2f8d375_4|py37h2f8d375_4|py35hdbf6ddf_4|py37hdbf6ddf_4|py37h2b20989_4|py27hdbf6ddf_3|py36hdbf6ddf_3|py37hdbf6ddf_3|py37h2b20989_3|py36h2b20989_3|py37hdbf6ddf_2|py27hdbf6ddf_2|py37h2b20989_2|py27h2b20989_2|py27h2b20989_1|py36hdbf6ddf_1|py27hdbf6ddf_1|py37h2b20989_1|py27hdbf6ddf_0|py35hdbf6ddf_0|py35h2b20989_0|py35h9be14a7_1|py27h9be14a7_1|py35h0ea5e3f_1|py27h0ea5e3f_1|py36h0ea5e3f_1|py36hde5b4d6_0']
```

There are not so many dependencies in my package so it is a mystery to me why it's not working

Comment: Can you try creating a new env that includes both your package and stellargraph from the start? Otherwise, please include a full YAML description of the env you are trying to install into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offhand i am not sure what the conflict you are seeing, or how to fix your environment, however I am able to install the stellargraph, sten and mono... packages from a fresh, base cloned environment. It may be more useful to build an environment from scratch, for others to use. Here are the commands I used:

```
conda create --name monomo --clone base
conda activate monomo
conda install -c monomonedula sten -c haasad
conda install -c stellargraph stellargraph


(monomo) C:\Users\me>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\me\miniconda3\envs\monomo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
gensim                    3.8.0            py37hf9181ef_0
...
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37hc3f5095_1
...
python                    3.7.6                h60c2a47_2
...
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h9439919_0
...
stellargraph              1.1.0                      py_0    stellargraph
sten                      0.1.0                      py_0    monomonedula
...
```

Maybe you can install all of these packages on one command with the versions listed.

I.E.
conda install scipy=1.4.1=py37h9439919_0 numpy-base=1.18.1=py37hc3f5095_1 and so on...